# Can I store data captured with a Watson conversation to an external file?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am looking to capture various answers from a Watson conversation to an external file for analytics. Also looking to capture the length of time a user spends on a session on the bot. First, I need to know whether this is possible and secondaly, the method to do so.

Answer (score 2):

This is really possible. You need to create one application to call the Watson Conversation Service, you can use one function inside the SDK to analyze the conversation.
You need to know: Watson Conversation service is one REST API endpoint, so you can build your app with Python, Java, PHP, Node, etc, and integrating with Watson Conversation.

You will need to use the SDK [Watson Developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud) for call Watson Services, and, for getting the conversation, you will need to use the `getLogs` [function](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/conversation/v1.js#L1516), and with this, you will access all conversation flows. And with your custom code, you'll store the data.

- See one example (Web application using Watson Conversation: [Conversation-simple with Nodejs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple)
- [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?node#) for calling the Conversation service and methods.
- See how to verify logs inside the [UI Conversation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/logs.html#about-the-improve-component).

Comment: I am using Python have the log access included in my tool at https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/

Comment: @data_henrik did one example using Python, awesome! Thank u for sharing your project.